# Python Pandas merge multiple CSV files with similar structure

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have tried all the instructions from here and just do not get on.
I want to use pandas to read all csv files from a folder and write them to a single dataframe.
The csv files are all almost the same, but in certain columns there is nothing in the first x-rows.
But I want to delete these lines anyway. The number of lines can vary though.
The whole thing seems to cause problems, because csv files with different structure can not be combined.
how could i work around this problem?

To illustrate, this is roughly what the dataset look like:

```
Dataset 1:
0 0 0 0 0 dont need this
0 0 5 0 0 dont need this
3 0 0 1 0 dont need this
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Dataset 2:
0 0 0 0 0 dont need this
0 0 2 0 0 dont need this
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Do you understand what i mean?

I have tried every instruction here, but nothing has worked.

EDIT:
I tried the example of @Tranbi.
Here is what i got:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from io import StringIO
    import os
    import io

path = '/path1234'
filelist = os.listdir(path)


dataset_list = [path + file for file in filelist]

cols = [f"col{i}" for i in range(0, 402)] # column names (here we expect 9 columns)

df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(dataset, sep="\t", names=cols) # set separator according to your actual data (default=',')
    for dataset in dataset_list
    ]
)

#df.dropna(axis = 0,how ='any',inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:
col0       col1       col2  col3  ...  col398  col399  col400  col401
0       0          0          0     0  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1       0          0          0    12  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2       0         18          0     0  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3      30          0         89     0  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4       0          0          0    36  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
..    ...        ...        ...   ...  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
206    30  22:17:04   22:23:14      0  ...     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
207    43  22:20:47   22:27:16      0  ...     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
208    43  22:24:28   22:30:57      0  ...     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
209    49  22:27:28   22:33:39      0  ...     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
210    43  22:34:44   22:41:13      0  ...     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0

[1375 rows x 402 columns]

If i use

```
df.dropna(axis = 0,how ='any',inplace=True)
```

The output doesnt work:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22, col23, col24, col25, col26, col27, col28, col29, col30, col31, col32, col33, col34, col35, col36, col37, col38, col39, col40, col41, col42, col43, col44, col45, col46, col47, col48, col49, col50, col51, col52, col53, col54, col55, col56, col57, col58, col59, col60, col61, col62, col63, col64, col65, col66, col67, col68, col69, col70, col71, col72, col73, col74, col75, col76, col77, col78, col79, col80, col81, col82, col83, col84, col85, col86, col87, col88, col89, col90, col91, col92, col93, col94, col95, col96, col97, col98, col99, ...]
Index: []

[0 rows x 402 columns]

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import glob


if __name__ == "__main__":
    combined_dataset = []
    for filename in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            data = file.read().split("\n")
        data = [elt for elt in data if len(elt.split(",")) == 9]
        combined_dataset.extend(data)

    print(combined_dataset)
```

I created 2 `csv` files containing the following:

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,5,0,0
3,0,0,1,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,2,0,0
4,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
6,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
7,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

The result is:

```
['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '4,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '6,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '7,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', '8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9']
```

Is this satisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the read csv directly with pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

dataset1 = StringIO("""0 0 0 0 0
0 0 5 0 0
3 0 0 1 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
""")

dataset2 = StringIO("""0 0 0 0 0
0 0 2 0 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
""")

dataset_list = [dataset1, dataset2] # your files in a list (use glob to get all csv files for exemple)
cols = [f"col{i}" for i in range(1, 10)] # column names (here we expect 9 columns)

df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(dataset, sep=" ", names=cols) # set separator according to your actual data (default=',')
    for dataset in dataset_list
    ]
).dropna()
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
3     1     2     3     4     5   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
4     1     2     3     4     5   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
5     1     2     3     4     5   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
2     1     2     3     4     5   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
3     1     2     3     4     5   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
4     1     2     3     4     5   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
5     1     2     3     4     5   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
6     1     2     3     4     5   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
```

Comment: Can you check my code i added in my question?

Comment: You end up with an empty df after dropna because there is at least one NA value per row. Are you sure there are 402 columns? If for example there are only 401 then you'll get an empty df

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have a defined number of columns (`N = 9` for example) and a list of your csv files in `filelist`, you can use:

```
N = 9
sep= r'\s+' # csv separator (here spaces)

out = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, names=range(N), sep=sep).dropna()
                 for f in filelist], ignore_index=True)
```